# In MIPS, how to use syscall 14 to read through a long file?

Tags: mips

I am currently working on a project (using `MARS`) where I need to read a multi-line file using `syscall 14`. I have a set buffer-length that I am using for the syscall that is 80-bytes long. I have set up my loop within a _readLine function so that the contents of the buffer should be printed to the console with each iteration. This is how I realized that my loop only reads the first `80`-bytes of a file, and nothing more.

I've been scouring the internet trying to find a hint on why I can't read the next `80`-bytes of the file. I thought it might have something to do with the file descriptor, but when I tried incrementing it, nothing changed, and it was still only outputting the first `80`-bytes of the file with `syscall 14`.

Can someone please help me figure out what is wrong, or give me an idea as how to point to the next `80` bytes of my file? My code is below (`fileBuff` holds the address of a user-inputted file name, and `_printBuffer` is a function I use later in my program but you can ignore).

```
 main:
    # Open file for reading
    addi $v0, $zero, 13
    la   $a0, fileBuff
    add  $a1, $zero, $zero # pass in flags
    add  $a2, $zero, $zero # pass in mode
    syscall                # open a file (file descriptor returned in $v0)
    add  $s6, $zero, $v0   # store descriptor in $a0

    jal _readLine    # call _readFile function
    jal _printBuffer

    addi $v0, $zero, 10 # prepare to exit the program
    syscall             # exit

_readLine:
    readLoop:
        add  $a0, $zero, $s6 # setup file descriptor
        la   $a1, buffer     # address of buffer
        addi $a2, $zero, 80  # read 80 bytes
        addi $v0, $zero, 14  # read from the file (descriptor already in $a0, buffer address in $a1, buffer length in $a2)
        syscall              # write to the file 

        beq $v0, $zero, doneReading
        slt $t0, $v0,   $zero       # if end of file, then close file
        beq $t0, 1,     doneReading # if error, then close file

        la  $t0, buffer     # load buffer address into $t0
        add $s6, $zero, $v0 # save file length in $s0
        add $s6, $s6,   $t0 # change descriptor to where last left off in the file

        #### remove... eventually
        addi $v0, $zero, 4
        la   $a0, buffer
        syscall
        ####

        j readLoop

    doneReading:

    addi $v0, $zero, 16  # syscall to close the file
    add  $a0, $zero, $s6 # file descriptor to close
    syscall              # close the file

    jr $ra
```

Answer (score 1):

Syscall 14 reads in a continuous string.

When you tell it to read 80-bytes, it will read 80 bytes.
When you call it again (without closing it), it will read the next 80 bytes and so on.

So I suggest you move this block of code:

```
addi $v0, $zero, 16  # syscall to close the file
add  $a0, $zero, $s6 # file descriptor to close
syscall              # close the file
```

into your main block right before the system exit call.